# Close vote limit display inconsistency

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I may just be missing something really obvious, but I seem to be getting mixed messages about my close votes on SO.

On my first vote to close, the popup tells me I have 50 votes remaining:

[image]

However, after voting to close for a while, I have apparently hit my 40 vote limit:

[image]

So my question is: is this a bug somewhere (either claiming I have too many votes, or not giving me enough), or does the 50 votes remaining refer to some other kind of vote that I'm blissfully unaware of?

I'm OK with my vote limit being 40 rather than 50, but it would be nice if the two figures agreed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing 2 different limits.

The review queue is not the *only* place you can cast close votes. You can also cast them directly on questions. The 50 vote limit applies to all site-wide votes to close questions.

The review queue itself is limited to 40 reviews. That doesn't only apply to voting to close; voting to leave open also counts against the review queue limit. *All* actions on a post except for `Skip` count, in fact.

As you can see from the message, you **reviewed** 40 close votes. Nowhere does it state that you **cast** 40 close votes yourself.

Comment: That means the OP either has 90 (40 reviewed + 50 remaining) close votes limit or he has reviewed all post as `Leave Open` (if he has 50 close votes limit). But looking at [his review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/318465/rivierakid?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1) mostly he voted to close. That means he has 90 close votes limit. Isn't it?

Comment: Interesting - that's exactly it. I still have 11 close votes if I click the close link on a question, and you're right, it did confuse me. Technically, reviewing existing close votes is not the same as simply casting a close vote, and this encourages wholly new votes.

Comment: @RivieraKid - Oh.. So you captured that image before starting closing votes review.

Comment: @MartjinPieters Now confusion cleared because of [OP's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161814/close-vote-limit-display-inconsistency#comment-470050). :)

Comment: @hims056: Glad you figured it out. :-)